# Solve only finds the trivial solution

Tags: equation-solving

I'm pretty sure `eqn1` and `eqn2` both have non-trivial solutions. They are a very similar set of simultaneous equations generated by another algorithm. Why does `Solve` only find the non-trivial solutions for `eqn1`? How can I find the solution for `eqn2`? Approximate solutions are fine.

```
eqn1 = {0.07739637024021674` x + 0.04` y + (0.` + 0.144` I) z == 0, 0.04` x + 0.037396370240216706` y + (0.` + 0.144` I) z == 
0, (0.` - 0.144` I) x - (0.` + 0.144` I) y + 
 0.5573963702402167` z == 0};
eqn2 = {0.07782393781203643` x + 0.04` y + (0.` + 0.145` I) z == 0, 0.04` x + 0.0378239378120364` y + (0.` + 0.145` I) z == 
0, (0.` - 0.145` I) x - (0.` + 0.145` I) y + 
 0.5578239378120364` z == 0};
Solve[eqn1]
Solve[eqn2]
```

(Sorry I know it's a bit of an eye sore)

Answer (score 2):

using `LinSolve` reports badly conditioned and returns trivial result too. You may write the equation in a matrix fashion, $m.v=v_0$, where $v={{x},{y},{z}}$ and $v_0$ is a vector whose elements are all zero. Here, your m matrix is hermitian so it can be diagonalized, and the solution to the equation can be found by finding the eigenvector of the matrix $m$ corresponding to eigenvalue 0 (x,y,z up to an overall normalizing factor: `c*x, c*y, c*z` also a solution for constant c):

```
m = (Table[
      CoefficientList[eqn2[[i]][[1]], #1, 2][[2]], {i, 1, 3}] & /@ {x,
      y, z})\[Transpose]

m == m\[HermitianConjugate]
(*True*)

{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[m]

{x, y, z} = evec[[3]]
(*3rd one corresponds to the zero eigenvalue for me*)
(*{1.11118*10^-16 + 0.0557919 I, -2.22045*10^-16 - 0.969765 I,0.237577 + 0. I}*)

(*copy eqn2 without ==0 to check*)
{0.07782393781203643` x + 0.04` y + (0.` + 0.145` I) , 
 0.04` x + 
  0.0378239378120364` y + (0.` + 0.145` I) z, (0.` - 
     0.145` I) x - (0.` + 0.145` I) y + 0.5578239378120364` z}

(*{-2.34119*10^-19 + 6.93889*10^-18 I, -3.95387*10^-18 + 5.55112*10^-17 I, 0. + 1.60843*10^-17 I}*)
```

solution (approximate)

```
{x, y, z} = Chop[{x, y, z}, N[10^-15]]
```

> {0. + 0.0557919 I, 0. - 0.969765 I, 0.237577}

Comment: A slick way to obtain the matrix `m` is to use `{b, m} = Normal @ CoefficientArrays[eqn2]`.

Comment: In fact, one could just do `NullSpace[Last[Normal[CoefficientArrays[eqn1, {x, y, z}]]]]`.

Comment: Nice, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

He is pretty sure there is a nontrivial solution to eqn2. So we want to be certain what the solution is, no hidden algorithm, no questionable decimals, no lurking potential division by zero, just and only simple obvious brute force steps of rationalizing the coefficients and adding the equations scaled by nonzero factors while showing the result of every step so that this can be checked.

For your eqn2 manually rationalize the three equations

```
 {007782393781203643/10^17 x + 004/100 y + (0 + 0145/1000 I) z == 0,
  004/100 x + 00378239378120364/10^16 y + (0 + 0145/1000 I) z == 0,
  (0 - 0145/1000 I) x - (0 + 0145/1000 I) y +  05578239378120364/10^16 z == 0}
```

Subtract the first from the second and a multiple of the first from the third to eliminate z.

```
{004/100 x + 00378239378120364/10^16 y + (0 + 0145/1000 I) z- 
   (007782393781203643/10^17 x + 004/100 y + (0 + 0145/1000 I) z ) == 0,
 (0 - 0145/1000 I) x - (0 + 0145/1000 I) y +  05578239378120364/10^16 z- 
   05578239378120364/10^16/(0 + 0145/1000 I)*
   (007782393781203643/10^17 x + 004/100 y + (0 + 0145/1000 I) z ) == 0}//Simplify
```

giving

```
{3782393781203643*x + 217606218796360*y == 0, 
 23615037390663710616808912749*x + 1358604970972000000000000000*y == 0}
```

subtract a multiple of the first from the second to eliminate x

```
{23615037390663710616808912749*x + 1358604970972000000000000000*y- 
  23615037390663710616808912749/3782393781203643*
  (3782393781203643*x + 217606218796360*y) == 0}//Simplify
```

giving

```
{y == 0}
```

and by inspection that means x==0 and by inspection that means z==0 is the only solution IF we can justify that rationalization.